# How to add a mention in the adaptive card for teams channel with bot framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am trying to mention a user in ms teams channel with the help of an adaptive card but there is no proper documentation for it and examples of the solution that is given here is not working? Has anybody has tried it please help with it

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JS?  I just posted a similar question, but it has a working solution for Users.  I'm attempting to mention a bot though.  [Here is the post I just submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546986/how-do-i-mention-a-bot-not-a-user-using-cardfactory-adaptivecard-nodejs-in-a)

```
CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
  $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
  type: 'AdaptiveCard',
  msteams: {
    entites: [
      {
        type: 'mention',
        text: '<at>(username)</at>',
        mentioned: {
          id: <userID>,
          name: <username>,
          role: 'user'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  body: [
    {
      type: 'TextBlock',
      text: '<at>(userName)</at>',
    }
  ]
});
```

This is the example I give

Answer (score 0):

I used to [use html to format cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#formatting-cards-with-html) in conversation bot. I think html is very flexible and here is my code.

```
private async Task showTeamStatus(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        MyInfo myInfo = new MyInfo();
        List <BotDataEntity> res = await myInfo.RunAsync();

        var card = new HeroCard();
        card.Title = "xxxx";
        var html = "<div>" +
            "<div style='height:40px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;'>" +
                "<div style='width:26%;float:left;text-align:left;'>Name</div>" +
                "<div style='width:20%;float:left;'>Log</div>" +
                "<div style='width:14%;float:left;'>Case</div>" +
                "<div style='width:14%;float:left;'>Task</div>" +
                "<div style='width:26%;float:left;'>IPD</div>" +
            "</div>";
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
        {
            html += "<div style='height:28px;line-height:28px;text-align:center;'>" +
                "<div style='float:left;width:26%;font-size:10px;text-align:left;'>" + res[i].userName + "</div>" +
                "<div style='float:left;width:20%;'>" + res[i].log + "</div>" +
                "<div style='float:left;width:14%;'>" + res[i].case + "</div>" +
                "<div style='float:left;width:14%;'>" + res[i].task + "</div>" +
                "<div style='float:left;width:26%;'>" + res[i].ipd + "</div>" +
            "</div>";
        }
        html += "</div> ";
        card.Text = html;

        var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
    }
```

You want to 'mention a user in ms teams channel', I think [this document](https://www.vrdmn.com/2020/02/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-send.html) may help you. It provides a sample on 'Post a proactive message in a Teams channel and mention a user in it'.