# How do I mention a Bot (not a user) using CardFactory.adaptiveCard (NodeJS) in a post to a channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I've scoured all four corners of interweb trying to find documentation on how to do this.  But my journey has been unsuccessful so far.  Part way through the search, I was able to find out how to mention a User (not a bot), and that was even a pain to find.  I found that you have to post a field named **msteams** at the top level of the "any" object parameter which is an object consisting of an entities array.  That array is an **array** of **objects**.  The following use of adaptiveCard works when mentioning a user with the proper values replacing **username** and **userID**:

```
CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
  $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
  type: 'AdaptiveCard',
  msteams: {
    entites: [
      {
        type: 'mention',
        text: '<at>(username)</at>',
        mentioned: {
          id: <userID>,
          name: <username>,
          role: 'user'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  body: [
    {
      type: 'TextBlock',
      text: '<at>(userName)</at>',
    }
  ]
});
```

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/cardfactory?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#adaptivecard-any-) of **CardFactory.adaptiveCard** just lists the parameter as an any Object and gives a small example not displaying an exhaustive list of fields of this parameter.  It also posts a link to the Adaptive Card documentation, but that's what it's abstracting and the fields are not 1:1 (point and case this msteams object that is never referenced in the Adaptive Card documentation from what I can tell).  I want to mention the bot itself that is posting this Adaptive Card.  I've attempted to replace the mentioned object with the following

```
  {
      "id": "a3216960-131c-11eb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "Bot",
      "role": "bot"
  }
```

This is equivalent to the object that I'm using to mention the "from" user in the adaptive card.  But this is the recipient.  The from user which is successfully mentioned is formatted like the following:

```
  {
      "id": "c3370a7c-95f2-4a60-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "User",
      "role": "user"
  }
```

Any help/guidance, tips, references would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Currently @mention a bot in Adaptive card is not supported. You can @mention user in Adaptive card.

Comment: ??  you can, or you cannot?

Comment: You can not @mention Bot in Adaptive card as of now