# How to mention a Bot (rather than a user) in a channel post using API?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are working on writing end-to-end tests for our Teams bot. To automate the process, we use another bot to send messages in the channel in order to simulate conversation. However, we are facing an issue when attempting to mention a bot in a channel using the same method that successfully mentions a user.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Mention a user by AAD Object Id: Hello <at>${userName} AAD</at>"
    }
  ],
  "msteams": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "mention",
        "text": "<at>${userName} AAD</at>",
        "mentioned": {
          "id": "${userAAD}",
          "name": "${userName}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The mention appears with highlighted text, but the displayed user is resolved as 'Unknown User' [Unknown User card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVHMq.png).

Is it possible to mention a bot? In [2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64549775/9666462), it was not possible. Is it now available in 2024?

I would appreciate guidance on correctly mentioning a bot using the Adaptive Card or even a plain text message via the Botframework API. Thanks!

Comment: This is currently not possible to mention bot using the Adaptive Card or plain text message. Currently you can only add user/tag mentions to your message - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=dotnet#add-mentions-to-your-messages.

Comment: Thanks, @Meghana-MSFT for the quick answer! Is there any other way that you recommend writing the end-to-end tests to simulate conversation in order to test that our bot is working properly?

Comment: Please refer this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/test-app-overview